# Two Centos Machines. Wildly different updates

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I have two CentOS Linux servers. One is dev and the other is prod. Dev is internal only and prod is exposed on port 80.

Both built at the same time and both configured pretty closely to the same with, perhaps, a few deviations on the dev box along the way...

They've always been within a day of each other when notifying me of updates. However, that changed this week.

Last weekend the dev box notified me of 3 updates. Kernel, kernel-headers and kernel-devel. I applied them. The prod box has yet to need those.

Yesterday, the dev box notified me of **178 updates**. I just manually ran a `sudo yum update` on prod. Still needs none.

Should I be concerned? Anything specifically that I should check? I can add the list of 178 packages on request...

- `Prod uname -a`

> Linux EFhermes 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 03:33:56 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

- `Dev uname -a`

> Linux EFhermesDev 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5.plus #1 SMP Fri Oct 9 12:34:43 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

**[Updated]**

3 hours after posting this (*24 hours after receiving update notifications for dev*) I just got notified by prod that he has 161 updates available... still no kernel, but lots of other "major" components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS 5.4 was just released.  I believe it's still making its way through the mirrors so check to see if the machines are using the same mirrors for their updates.

Comment: He's already got 5.4 on the Prod server, that is evident by the kernel version 2.6.18-164.

Comment: 5.4 was just released? Where do you find that out? The CentOS site is sure hiding it...

Comment: Yeah they haven't updated their website but I saw the news on my RSS feed of distrowatch.com.

Comment: It was also announced on CentOS's mailing list.   http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2009-October/016195.html

Comment: @3dinfluence Thanks. I'm on that list, but just realized I haven't been getting anything from it. Reckon I'll go check the spam traps...

Comment: Yeah, it sure looks like I'm getting a version upgrade with all these patches -- especially now that prod has joined in.

Answer (score 7):

On developer machine repository centosplus is probably enabled.

Comment: enabled on both, actually (not that I recall *WHY*...)

Comment: I stand corrected. NOT enabled on prod.

Comment: Sounds like the issue to me

Comment: It may account for the (now currently) discrepancy of a couple dozen. Originally I was more freaked about the 178 discrepancy!

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
yum clean all
```

To remove the cached headers, etc.  Then try the update or check-update again.

Comment: good idea, but no change.

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of `cat /etc/issue` on both systems?

Comment: on dev it is 
<blockquote>CentOS release 5.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
</blockquote>  

On prod it is the same.

Comment: Hm. Ok. Then my idea wasn't it.